# Leibniz rule Exterior Covariant Derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, connections

I'm reading *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis* by Jost and the way he defines the exterior covariant derivative comes naturally using the definition of the induced connection on the tensor product.

> **Definition 3.1.4** Let $E_{1}, E_{2}$ be vector bundles over M with connections D1, D2 resp. The induced connection D on $E=E_{1}\otimes E_{2}$ is defined by the requirement
> $$D(\mu_{1}\otimes \mu_{2})=D_{1}\mu_{1}\otimes \mu_{2}+\mu_{1}\otimes D_{2}\mu_{2}$$
> for $\mu_{i}\in\Gamma(E_{i})$, $i=1,2$.

So, in order to extend a connection $D$, defined on a vector bundle $E$, from $\Gamma(E)$ to $\Gamma(E)\otimes\Omega^{p}(M)$, $0\leq p \leq \dim M$, he requires
$$D(\mu\otimes \omega )=D\mu\wedge \omega+\mu\otimes d\omega$$
for $\mu\in\Gamma(E)$, $\omega \in \Omega^{p}(M)$. But in the bibliography I came across with the Leibniz rule for the exterior covariant derivative
$$D(\omega\otimes \mu )=d\omega\otimes\mu+(-1)^{p}\omega\wedge D\mu$$
and I am wondering, if we were to extend D from $\Gamma(E)$ to $\Omega^{p}(M)\otimes\Gamma(E)$ using again the definition for the tensor product, then wouldn't we require
$$D(\omega\otimes \mu )=d\omega\otimes\mu+\omega\wedge D\mu \ ?$$
In other words, were does the $(-1)^{p}$ sign hide when we use the above definition? Thanks in advance.

Comment: An exterior covariant derivative is a completely different construction. The product connection requires a connection $D_1$ on the first factor, while the exterior covariant derivative instead uses the exterior derivative $d$, which is *not* a connection.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer! I was under the misapprehension that the exterior derivative was a connection on $\Omega^{p}(M)$ since it suffices the Leibniz rule. If this isn't the case, do you think that there exist a connection $D_1$ on $\Omega^{p}(M)$ so that the extension of $D$ on $E$-valued forms of degree $p>0$ coincides with the tensor connection of $D_1$ and $D$?

Comment: But at the same time, if there exist, we would treat $\omega$ as a section of $\Lambda^{p}T*M$ of degree $0$, and still not having the $(-1)^{p}$ sign. So, basically, my question is whether we can derive the exterior covariant derivative using the tensor product definition.

Comment: The exterior derivative is required to follow a different product rule:$$d(f\omega)=fd\omega+(df)\wedge\omega$$Where $f\in C^\infty M$, $\omega\in\Omega^kM$. Even if we identify $\Omega^kM$ with the subspace of alternating $k$-tensors in the standard way, this product rule will be distinct from the one for connections, since it has $df\wedge\omega$ rather than $df\otimes\omega$.  The prblem isn't the $(-1)^p$, rather it is that $d\omega$ does not behave like a covariant derivative for $p>0$.